# How does one make the array bigger?

Tags: c++, arrays

So first let me explain what problem I'm running into.

```
long long int a[2147483647] = {1,1};
```

error: size of array 'a' exceeds maximum object size '2147483647'

And changed the "long long int" to many other data type, for example:

- long int
- unsigned int
- unsigned long

and some other random date type and also the number in bracket (bigger than 2000000000) the but found the same error, which makes me think inside the array's max amount isn't affected by data type and it's also much smaller than 2147483647.

Can someone explain plus tell me how to fix this problem yet still having the amount over the 2000000000 limit?

Comment: Use a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: `long long int a[2147483647] = {1,1};` -- Honestly, this should not be the way to solve the issue.  Why must you have arrays of such massive size?  Also, arrays declared this size is usually done in those "online competition" coding sites.  I've always said that this is just lazy C++ programming to declare arrays this way.

Comment: Even switching to x64 is no guarantee of success. If ever there was an XY problem, this is it. The question of "needing" effectively 15 gB of contiguous addressable storage suggests there is a more overbearing issue at work here.

Comment: it also depends on how and where you declared the array and compiled/linked the program, because arrays at global scope will be different from arrays in local scope, and programs with more stack space can handle different array sizes

Comment: FWIW [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Comment: I wouldn't change randomly "*many other data type*" but focus on the integer literal that sets the array size. Since c++11 a `llu` suffix tells the compiler that you need a `long long unsigned int`?